# .NET - how does IndexOf work if I don't implement IComparable in my class?

Tags: .net, collections

I have a collection of custom object, and I am doing IndexOf to find the index of a specific object.  I would assume that the IndexOf would use IComparable implementation to check to see if the objects match, but I am not implementing it in my class.

How does IndexOf determine that two objects are equal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear which type you're calling `IndexOf` on anyway, but most collections won't use `IComparable` anyway - they'll just use `Equals` and do a linear search. Unless you've overridden `Equals` (or implemented `IEquatable<T>`), a class will be compared by reference identity, and a struct will have auto-generated equality comparisons. `IComparable` would be used for something like a binary search of a sorted list.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx) for the List(T).IndexOf Method:

> This method determines equality using
>   the default equality comparer
>   EqualityComparer(T).Default for T, the type of
>   values in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison is done using `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`.

`EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will return a default implementation if one exists...otherwise it uses an implementation based on `Object.Equals()` which I'm guessing is what is being used in your case.

Unless you've either overriden `Equals()` or implemented `IEquatable<T>`, `Object.Equals()` will check for reference equality only.